# Generality of rings' abelian group

Tags: group-theory, ring-theory, finite-groups

Let G be an abelian (finite) group. Is there a ring $R$ with $G$ isomorphic to the group $(R,+)$?

Comment: Do you require rings to have a unit?

Comment: If a unit does limit the generality of group structure: No.

Comment: Then every abelian group is the additive group of a ring, with the trivial multiplication $x\cdot y = 0$.

Comment: Does that mean that existence of a unit limits the group structure?

Comment: Not for finite groups. I overlooked that condition.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Even if you require rings to have $1$, since every finite abelian group is isomorphic to the direct product of $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$'s, you can just extend this into a ring in the obvious way, where the $1$ is achieved by letting each factor equal $1$.

Answer (score 5):

The result is still true even if you ask that $G$ is finitely generated. This is because every finitely generated abelian group is product of a finite number of cyclic groups which in turn are isomorphic other to $\Bbb Z$ or $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$, and these are also rings.